# Draw the LaTex beamer article symbol

Tags: beamer, symbols

How do I draw the little article symbol from LaTeX beamer's bibliography section somewhere else in my beamer presentation?

I want to use it as a bullet symbol for a normal list.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 10):

You can set the `itemize item` template to use the `bibliography item` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\leavevmode\usebeamertemplate*{bibliography item}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here it is …

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\articon}{\pgfuseimage{beamericonarticle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
Here it is

\pgfuseimage{beamericonarticle}

Or with the command \verb+\articon+

\articon
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```