# LaTex Beamer - Article Symbol

Tags: beamer, symbols, article

How can I draw Beamer's article symbol outside the `\documentclass[beamer]` environment? I need something [like this guy was trying to accomplish](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/draw-the-latex-beamer-article-symbol), but on a regular LaTeX file (`\documentclass[article]`).

I haven't seen in any other topic what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{beamericonarticle}
\end{document}
```

(it is just an image - no beamer magic)

Comment: Oh! I was trying to do magic with the `\usepackage{pgfbaseimage}`... Thank you very much for the simplest solution.